# Is there a way to write a macro pattern that somehow avoids preprocessor prescan expansion?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I'm wondering if there exists a pattern of writing preprocessor macros that can effectively "skip" prescan macro expansion.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT(label) label##_SHIFT
#define WIDTH(label) label##_WIDTH

#define MSB(label) label##_SHIFT + label##_WIDTH

#define A_SHIFT 0
#define A_WIDTH 4

#if 1
#define B_SHIFT 4
#else
/* Something like this would be preferred over, say
 * #define B_SHIFT A_SHIFT + A_WIDTH
 */
#define B_SHIFT MSB(A)  
#endif
#define B_WIDTH 4

int main(int argv, char ** argc) {
    (void)argv;
    (void)argc;

    (void)printf("A: Width %d\n", WIDTH(A));
    (void)printf("A: Shift %d\n", SHIFT(A));
    (void)printf("A: MSB   %d\n", MSB(A));

    (void)printf("B: Width %d\n", WIDTH(B));
    (void)printf("B: Shift %d\n", SHIFT(B));
    (void)printf("B: MSB   %d\n", MSB(B));
    return 0;
}
```

In the contrived example above, if the second form of the `B_SHIFT` macro is used, the macro definition in the first scan of the preprocessor wants to expand `A`, which (of course) it can't.

Is there some preprocessor trickery that can be employed so that it could effectively do the second form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the contrived example above, if the second form of the B_SHIFT macro is used, the macro definition in the first scan of the preprocessor wants to expand A, which (of course) it can't.

The problem here is that you've arranged for the substitution of `MSB(B)` to itself try to do the substitution `MSB(A)`. The C preprocessor does not allow recursive substitution of the same macro, even in cases like this where the recursion is entirely safe. Within a macro substitution, the name of the macro being substituted is effectively undefined. The fact that you see an error message referring to `A` is a consequence of `MSB(A)` being passed through unaltered, with the result that both `MSB` and `A` appear as tokens after preprocessing. Since neither has been declared, the compiler complains about the use of an undeclared function (`MSB`) and variable (`A`).

One simple (but obviously not ideal) fix is to use two identical macro definitions:

```
#define SHIFT(label) label##_SHIFT
#define WIDTH(label) label##_WIDTH

#define MSB(label) label##_SHIFT + label##_WIDTH
#define MSB_(label) label##_SHIFT + label##_WIDTH

#define A_SHIFT 0
#define A_WIDTH 4
#define B_SHIFT MSB_(A)  
#define B_WIDTH 4
```

That will allow the expansion of `B_SHIFT` to be expanded inside an expansion of `MSB(B)`.

If you want to see what a different solution might look like, you can take a look at the [Boost Preprocessor library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/reentrancy.html).

Comment: So if I wanted to expand the macros to `C_SHIFT/WIDTH`, `D_SHIFT/WIDTH` while daisy chaining the `MSB()` macros, my only recourse would be to add more MSB definitions with increasing underscores (or other unique identifier)?

Comment: @jamie: it's the length of the daisy chain which matters. That's the point of the strategy in the boost-pp link.